# AIR Android GCM ANE Cannot get Registration Id using action script 3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, google-cloud-messaging

I am using http://myappsnippet.com/gcm/ to make push notification in my games, as it support icon, sound, and vibration, which make notification meaningful.

Here is my Code:

```
var gcm:Gcm = new Gcm(senderId); 
gcm.addEventListener(GcmEvent.REGISTERED, onRegistered);
gcm.vibrate = true;
gcm.showNotificationWhenAppRunning = true;
gcm.register();
trace(gcm.getRegistrationId); //get a blank String ""
trace(gcm.check()); // get false
```

If I run it on my device (android 4.3), I succeed to get gcm.getRegistrationId, and get true in gcm.check();
However, if I run it on other devices (android 4.0 / 4.1), I get blank string and false.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
       trace(_ex.getRegistrationId);
```